Is GHC strict field packing the same as using unboxed types explicitly?
I believe if I make a constructor like:
data MyThing = MyThing 
  Word8# 
  Word8# 
  Word8# 
  Word8#

GHC (with optimisations turned on) will now pack the unboxed words within one word, instead of having them take 8 bytes each.
What if I do:
data MyThing = MyThing 
  {-# UNPACK #-} !Word8 
  {-# UNPACK #-} !Word8 
  {-# UNPACK #-} !Word8 
  {-# UNPACK #-} !Word8

Does the same packing happen?

Yes, both versions of MyThing have the same in-memory layout.  You can observe this by compiling the following program with:
ghc -O -ddump-cmm -ddump-asm -fforce-recomp -dsuppress-all Thing8.hs 

and studying the resulting CMM or assembly.  With this program:
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}

module Thing8 where

import Data.Word
import GHC.Base
import GHC.Word

data MyThing1 = MyThing1
  Word8#
  Word8#
  Word8#
  Word8#

data MyThing2 = MyThing2
  {-# UNPACK #-} !Word8
  {-# UNPACK #-} !Word8
  {-# UNPACK #-} !Word8
  {-# UNPACK #-} !Word8

foo :: MyThing1 -> MyThing2
foo (MyThing1 a b c d) = MyThing2 (W8# a) (W8# b) (W8# c) (W8# d)

the core CMM code for foo is:
 cJG:
     _sID::I8 = I8[R1 + 7];
     _sIE::I8 = I8[R1 + 8];
     _sIF::I8 = I8[R1 + 9];
     _sIG::I8 = I8[R1 + 10];
     I64[Hp - 8] = MyThing2_con_info;
     I8[Hp] = _sID::I8;
     I8[Hp + 1] = _sIE::I8;
     I8[Hp + 2] = _sIF::I8;
     I8[Hp + 3] = _sIG::I8;
     R1 = Hp - 7;
     Sp = Sp + 8;
     call (P64[Sp])(R1) args: 8, res: 0, upd: 8;

and you can see here that 4 consecutive bytes are copied from the source object to the newly created heap object.
In this case, the native code generator is not clever enough to rewrite this as a single word-sized move and leaves it as four byte-sized moves (see the assembly) even if compiled with -O2, but the LLVM backend will optimize it correctly if you compile with -fllvm.
